# php file_get_contents from ashx url

Tags: php, ashx

I am trying to list the contents of a webpage contents using `file_get_contents`. Page type seems to be a `ashx`?

However if  I were to use a url such as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629504/php-file-get-contents-very-slow-when-using-full-url`. it works

the code

```
$lines = file_get_contents('http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=321&f=sh_price_u1&r=11');
echo $lines;
```

Comment: it generates simple html so you can easily do what you want to

Comment: also you get your html in just one line, if you want to get it line-by-line you should use [file](http://php.net/file)

Comment: So what's wrong?  What happens that isn't supposed to or doesn't happen that is supposed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code, the file length should be increased

Please find the function [load()](http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/load/) and call it,

```
<?php
$url = "http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=321&f=sh_price_u1&r=1";
$result = load($url,$options);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: this works. thanks
load function was found at: http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/load/