# PHP - Read and write the same file hangs

Tags: php, ffmpeg, progress, file-writing, file-read

I'm trying to use FFMPEG to make some works with video on the server, and something I need to do is to get the progress of the process.

I searched a little and I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441517/ffmpeg-progress-bar-encoding-percentage-in-php) which tells to write the log into a file and then reading and parsing it.

## The problem

What is driving me crazy is that I tell FFMPEG - with `exec` - (*process A*) to write the log into a file, but when I try to read it - with `file_get_contents()` - (*process B*) it does not show the contents until *process A* is finished (or interrupted the PHP script).

So, when *process A* finishes or it says "PHP script timeout", then I can read the file as times as I want, refreshing the page (*process B*) and showing the contents at the time.

## What I've tried

I've tried to use `fopen()` to create the file with `w`, `w+` and `a` parameters, using - and without using - `fclose()`. I've tried to use also `flock()` just in case it gets faster to read to *process B* if it knows it's already locked and does not have to wait, but then FFMPEG is not able to write into the file.

I've searched for [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications) too, but I think there must be an easier and simpler way.

I've used also CURL and HTTP context, as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629504/php-file-get-contents-very-slow-when-using-full-url) suggests, but no luck.

I've tried, too, to use PHP-FFMPEG but it's not supporting the last FFMPEG version, so I cannot use it.

*When I said before "(or interrupted the PHP script)" is because I tried to wait and, when PHP got a timeout,* process B *worked alright and the file was still updating.*

## The code

### Process A (fileA.php)

`exec('ffmpeg -y -i input_file.mp4 output_file.avi 2> C:\Full\Path\To\File\log.txt 1>&2');`

### Process B (fileB.php)

```
$content = file_get_contents($file);

if($content){
    //get duration of source
    preg_match("/Duration: (.*?), start:/", $content, $matches);

    $rawDuration = $matches[1];

    //rawDuration is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
    $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawDuration));
    $duration = floatval($ar[0]);
    if (!empty($ar[1])) $duration += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
    if (!empty($ar[2])) $duration += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

    //get the time in the file that is already encoded
    preg_match_all("/time=(.*?) bitrate/", $content, $matches);

    $rawTime = array_pop($matches);

    //this is needed if there is more than one match
    if (is_array($rawTime)){$rawTime = array_pop($rawTime);}

    //rawTime is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
    $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawTime));
    $time = floatval($ar[0]);
    if (!empty($ar[1])) $time += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
    if (!empty($ar[2])) $time += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

    //calculate the progress
    $progress = round(($time/$duration) * 100);

    echo "Duration: " . $duration . "<br>";
    echo "Current Time: " . $time . "<br>";
    echo "Progress: " . $progress . "%";

}
```

### The process

I just open `fileA.php` on a Chrome tab and, after a few seconds, I open `fileB.php` on another Chrome tab (and it stays as *loading*).

### What I need

I need to be able to load the file and show the information I want to show while the file is being written (by `exec` and `FFMPEG` or other PHP scripts), so I can update the progress percentage with some AJAX calls.

### Extra information

At this point, I'm using PHP 5.4 on a IIS 7.5 with Windows 7 Professional.

Thank you everyone for your time, help and patience!

Best regards.

Comment: Have you verified that the `Log.txt` gets written and filled with content before Process A finishes?

Comment: Yes! It gets! I can, in fact, open the file with Notepad and see the text, and it still gets written if I close it and open it again.

Comment: However, in case it does not get written, I should see a blank screen because the script has already loaded all the content (it is, none), but I get a "loading" screen until process A crashes or finishes...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is working now. After so many tries without working, the only modification I did that seems to get sense is writing `session_write_close()` **before** calling the `exec` command. So, following my example, it would be something like:

```
session_write_close();
exec('ffmpeg -y -i input_file.mp4 output_file.avi 2> C:\Full\Path\To\File\log.txt 1>&2');
```

Now, I'd be very pleased if someone told me if this makes any sense or if it has to do with something else I cannot see.

Thank you!

Comment: Now it's not working again at some points... it randomly works and stops working. I will try to check my IIS and PHP configurations, because I can not understand nothing. Thank you everyone for your time, anyway!