# Slow response of Insagram API when using file_get_contents()

Tags: php, instagram, file-get-contents, instagram-api, php-curl

I'm working with old Instagram API.
It works fast if I use cUrl, but I have to use sockets or file_get_contents() - then it takes 10+ seconds to response.

I have tried sending various headers like 'Connection: close' and using http 1.0/1.1 - but nothing helped.

Here code samples:

cUrl

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=some_token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($res);
```

file_get_contents()

```php
$res = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=some_token");
print_r($res);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629504/php-file-get-contents-very-slow-when-using-full-url

Comment: @zvi I think it's not DNS problem, because when I use cUrl it works fast. I have also tried sending 'Connection: close' header and that haven't helped. I'm running PHP 7.1

Answer (score 1):

cUrl is always faster then `file_get_contents()` we also try this both in our site but the best way is cUrl.that response faster then file_get_contents().

> if you set header like `'Connection: close'` but you can't get response faster