# file_get_contents() take times to load contents via external server - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get contents of somes files via another server with PHP using `file_get_contents()` and `file()`. Everything's fine but it takes a lot of times to load the page. Otherwise, if I get contents of a local file, it takes like 0,2 secs. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629504/php-file-get-contents-very-slow-when-using-full-url) method but it didn't work.

Is there a way to get the content of the file quicker and still using PHP? Or combine PHP with js?

Thank you!

Comment: I mean, if the external server is slow, the external server is slow.

Comment: No matter it's `file_get_contents()` or using cURL, downloading a file from the Internet takes time. For better UX, you should use AJAX to display a loading effect instead.

Comment: Server speed should be fine, because when I open the file directly in my browser, this is almost instant.

Comment: from local server commandline `ping otherserver`