# Upload File in laravel very slow

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on uploading video file in laravel but the problem that it takes much time as it could reached to 2-3 minutes

This is the snippet of code

```
if($courseclass->video !="")
                    {
                        $content = @file_get_contents(public_path().'/video/class/'.$courseclass->video);

                        if ($content) {
                            unlink(public_path().'/video/class/'.$courseclass->video);
                        }
                    }
```

Do anyone has an idea about this ,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which of these parts takes so much time? I don't see any code handling an upload

Answer (score 2):

You can use php's `file_exists()` method instead of `file_get_contents()`

Comment: file_exists get the file content as same as file_get_contents?

Answer (score 0):

You are using php main function which is file_get_contents this is probably the main cause. My suggestion is to use the default file upload feature from Laravel [file system storage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem)

This slow upload problem happened at [file_get_contents very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629504/php-file-get-contents-very-slow-when-using-full-url) because it uses the basic function file_get_contents. Hopefully useful, thank you.